# Check if a type only has pure virtual methods?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

You can use `<type_traits>` (in C++11) to check whether a class is [abstract](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_abstract). However, this only checks whether **any** method is pure virtual. But, you could have other methods which are either not-polymorphic at all, or at least, not pure virtual.

I'd like to check whether a class has *only* pure-virtual methods. The intention is to enforce a class to be an interface-only class (eg. by `static_assert`). There doesn't appear to be a built-in trait for this - am I missing it, or is there some reasonable combination of the existing ones to accomplish this?

Comment: Since that class would have virtual methods, it would have a vtable that needs to be set up in a constructor (redirecting all function calls to stubs that would report "a call of pure virtual function" error).  The constructor would not be pure virtual.  So no class could pass your check, unless you exclude the constructor (and possibly an implicit destructor as well).

Comment: I don't think it is currently possible to implement such a check in plain standard C++. What for do you need this check? Maybe we could instead help find a way to do what you're ultimately trying to do…

Comment: And the same applies to the destructor AFAIK - it would be either virtual or non-virtual (can be also default) but it cannot be pure.

Comment: As I said, I'm trying to enforce an interface-only class. I don't want others to create any implementations within the interface, only in derived classes. It's a fair answer that it's not possible, but, I wanted to know :).

Comment: Do you mean that C++ isn't turing complete @MichaelKenzel :p ?

Comment: Couldn't one try to instantiate it in a context where it's not required to compile as-such, but just be syntactically valid? I'm thinking something along the lines of `declval`, `if constexpr`, SFINAE or similar might provide a solution.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You could maybe do that to check if a specific function is pure virtual, or if the class is abstract but I don't see how this could be used to detect that an abstract class has a non-pure virtual member function.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Hmm, yeah, you are probably right.

Comment: @FlorentJousse C++ is definitely turing complete. C++ is not (yet) reflective at compile time however… ;-)

Comment: Probably easier/better to add that rule in a linter (you should be able to do it with clang tooling).

Comment: @axalis [Destructors can be pure.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Pure_virtual_destructors)

Comment: @Oktalist Hm, actually two different interpretations of `pure`: just delcared with `= 0` (i. e. no entry in vtable) or strictly not having any definition. Pure virtual destructor somehow appears to be a hybrid between normal virtual and what we usually understand by pure virtual functions...

Comment: @Aconcagua `=0` just means that any constructible derived class must override the function. It's possible to provide a definition for a function declared with `=0`. It can sometimes make sense to do so, and _not just_ for destructors. And of course it's also possible to omit the definition of a non-pure function, provided it is never called.